# add a unique id for each entry in json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as following :

[image]

I would like for each entry that has the attribute `title` to add a unique id, so my json object would look like this :

[image]

and in another version I want to add a unique id for each entry, so it would look like this:

[image]

How can I do that  ?

## Edit:

This is my json object : https://api.myjson.com/bins/59prd

Comment: use [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop over the object and add an identifier.

Comment: please add the code/objects as text, not as image.

Comment: @NinaScholz, please check my edit

Comment: @YukinaSpoonatte, please have a look here: [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop over the object and add unique identifiers.

```
var iterator = 0; // this is going to be your identifier

function addIdentifier(target){
  target.id = iterator;
  iterator++;
}

function loop(obj){

  for(var i in obj){

    var c = obj[i];        

    if(typeof c === 'object'){

      if(c.length === undefined){

        //c is not an array
        addIdentifier(c);

      }

      loop(c);

    }

  }

}

loop(json); // json is your input object
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your solution as it's cleaner by using recursion and being split up into reuseable methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure `addId` for the callback for iterateing the array and use the inner callback `iter` for nested arrays.

With the call `addId`, you can specify an index to start with.

```js
function addId(id) {
    return function iter(o) {
        if ('title' in o) {
            o.id = id++;
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            Array.isArray(o[k]) && o[k].forEach(iter);
        });
    };
}

var data = [{ "Arts": [{ "Performing arts": [{ "Music": [{ "title": "Accompanying" }, { "title": "Chamber music" }, { "title": "Church music" }, { "Conducting": [{ "title": "Choral conducting" }, { "title": "Orchestral conducting" }, { "title": "Wind ensemble conducting" }] }, { "title": "Early music" }, { "title": "Jazz studies" }, { "title": "Musical composition" }, { "title": "Music education" }, { "title": "Music history" }, { "Musicology": [{ "title": "Historical musicology" }, { "title": "Systematic musicology" }] }, { "title": "Ethnomusicology" }, { "title": "Music theory" }, { "title": "Orchestral studies" }, { "Organology": [{ "title": "Organ and historical keyboards" }, { "title": "Piano" }, { "title": "Strings, harp, oud, and guitar" }, { "title": "Singing" }, { "title": "Strings, harp, oud, and guitar" }] }, { "title": "Recording" }] }, { "Dance": [{ "title": "Choreography" }, { "title": "Dance notation" }, { "title": "Ethnochoreology" }, { "title": "History of dance" }] }, { "Television": [{ "title": "Television studies" }] }, { "Theatre": [{ "title": "Acting" }, { "title": "Directing" }, { "title": "Dramaturgy" }, { "title": "History" }, { "title": "Musical theatre" }, { "title": "Playwrighting" }, { "title": "Puppetry" }] }] }] }];

data.forEach(addId(1))
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```