# How to run javascript to change a json scheme

Tags: javascript, json

I found a way to use javascript to change a json file, I never studied javascript so all I know that it runs on web browsers. How do you run this script? newbie here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972448/15931705

the script;

```
var iterator = 0; // this is going to be your identifier

function addIdentifier(target){
  target.id = iterator;
  iterator++;
}

function loop(obj){

  for(var i in obj){

    var c = obj[i];        

    if(typeof c === 'object'){

      if(c.length === undefined){

        //c is not an array
        addIdentifier(c);

      }

      loop(c);

    }

  }

}

loop(json); // json is your input object
```

json; https://api.myjson.com/bins/59prd

Comment: You can run js code in the webrowsers console, which you can find under your webrowsers webtools/inspector

Comment: @Breezer There is a json file which never said where to put it in that answer. I don't know how to connect the json file to the script.

Comment: open the json file in your browser, then open your browsers console  and run the code? Or if you want to make an application, then you could read the file programmatically with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader, and afterwards run whatever code you like on the content

Comment: @Breezer I opened and did what you said. >open the json file in your browser, then open your browsers console and run the code

Comment: @Breezer now it says; Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: change the last row of your code to
`loop(JSON.parse(document.all[0].innerText))`

Answer (score 1):

You can run js scripts outside browser by using [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/). First, install node js globally in machine. Then, navigate cmd to the directory where your script located and run `node script_name.js`

Comment: okay, I already installed node.js, with this code. where do I put the json file?

Comment: same folder as the script, and your code need to read the the json file also.

Comment: a reference to read json file in node js https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/ or you can google more other methods